# Can't Login to Amadeus, error during login call

Tags: authentication, amadeus

[login error page is drops me on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J8ys.png)

Every time I try to login it just drops me off on this page with an error saying "error during login call" and it doesn't actually sign me in. Anyone know what might be causing this? I need help! Thank you :)

Comment: There is an on-going issue under investigation on the portal. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

same happended for me but i think may be it is based on the network issue i mean based on type of internet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).